# Can I configure bugzilla to suggest existing?

Tags: bugzilla

When I ask a question here, a list of  "Related Questions" pops up.  Is there a plugin for bugzilla that will make the same thing happen for us?

Comment: You might be better asking this on Stack Overflow as there are probably more bugzilla users there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugzilla 4.0 has a automatic duplicate detection feature which does essentially what you want. http://www.bugzilla.org/releases/4.0/release-notes.html#v40_feat